# Why are characters drawn differently in every shot in Hakushon Daimaou?

Tags: anime-production, the-genie-family

Unlike CGI or stop-motion, hand-drawn animation allows the artist to do a lot of drawings, although characters will be drawn differently on the next shots which the animation is either made by one animator or different animators.

In *Hakushon Daimaou*, the characters are drawn differently constantly in every shot. For example, Daimaou's face would be drawn differently in various shots, Akubi's eyes would be bigger than usual in various shots, and Kan-Chan sometimes looks thick or thin in some shots. In episode 14a, Yuriko is drawn in great detail which looks good when I first saw when I watched it in Italian.

Why are the characters in the show drawn differently? Is there a reason for this?

Comment: ***IF*** you are talking about the original show and not the 2020 remake, then I fear your are simply expecting too much quality from something that was made back in ***1969***... I mean, if that looks "bad" to you... try to watch characters proportions in different scenes in the original version of  Human Monster BEM

Comment: It's not bad, the animation in the original show wasn't the best, but you can notice that the characters in this show are drawn differently in between shots, did the artists draw the characters from memory when they were doing this?